# How do you make variables increase simultaneously

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

```
graphicsListVert = {};
graphicsListHor = {};
Do[{
 AppendTo[graphicsListVert, Line[{{n, p}, {n, p - 2}}]],
 AppendTo[graphicsListHor, Line[{{n, p - 2}, {n + 2, p - 2}}]]
},
{n, 0, 1, 1}, {p, 2, 0, -2}]
```

I want `p` and `n` to simultaneously increase and decrease respectively

Answer (score 1):

```
n = Range[0, 1, 1]
p = Range[2, 0, -2]
graphicsListVert = MapThread[Line[{{#1, #2}, {#1, #2 - 2}}] &, {n, p}]
graphicsListHor = 
 MapThread[Line[{{#1, #2 - 2}, {#1 + 2, #2 - 2}}] &, {n, p}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new list with the set of values. For example

```
list = Transpose[{Range[0, 1, 1], Range[2, 0, -2]}];    
graphicsListVert = {};
graphicsListHor = {};

Do[{{n, p} = x; 
AppendTo[graphicsListVert, Line[{{n, p}, {n, p - 2}}]],
AppendTo[graphicsListHor, Line[{{n, p - 2}, {n + 2, p - 2}}]]}
,{x, list}]
```